# Typescript rest parameter in the middle of arguments list

Tags: arguments, typescript

I would like to declare a function which last parameter is always a callback. However when i do:

```
interface Statement extends events.EventEmitter {
    bind(...args, callback?:(err?:Error)=>void) : Statement;
}
```

I get an error

```
error TS1014: Rest parameter must be last in list
```

Is it possible in **typescript** to heve **Rest parameter** not as a last param in the argument list? Is there any hack that could help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't supported in TypeScript. The best you can do is `...args: any[]`, or only use libraries with more sensible parameter orderings.

Comment: I know it's a long shot, but with all the changes since Feb 2014, is there perhaps a better way to hack this together now? The folks at RxJS are using methods where they need to accept a variable number of observables as the first set of arguments, and an optional final argument of a different type ([here's](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/src/operator/concat.ts) one example). Would variadic kinds perhaps help here?

Comment: Now you could use a union type for the rest arg e.g. `function foo(first: string, ...middleNumberAndFinalBoolean: Array<number|boolean>)`. This is somewhat safer than `any`.

Answer (score 21):

While a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) needs to be the last one, you can now use  [variadic tuple types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) in TS 4.0:

```
type VarCallback<T extends any[]> = (...args: [...T, (err?: Error) => void]) => void
```

`VarCallback` ensures, the *last* function parameter is a callback type `(err?: Error) => void`.

For example, declare a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types) with the first two parameters `string` and `number`:

```
type MyCallback = VarCallback<[string, number]>
// (a1: string, a2: number, a3: (err?: Error | undefined) => void) => void

const myCb: MyCallback = (s, n, cb) => {/* your implementation */ }
// s,n,cb are strongly typed now
```

[Live code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwMJwDaoEZwMYGsA8AKlBAB7AQB2AJgM5RyUgDaAugHxQC8UAFAHSDEAc1oAuKM0H9CAGj4QECAPwSAokoD2CAJTdOAN00BLaqz1dDJ6gCgboSFACyIFOix5usRG8w4CzLTACMaUwvKUAK4AthiKHDYA9Il8cACMEkEhYfJwAEwSUbGKuQDMEryKKupaCFAAPlCRNBAAZqEQ1BZWpt1QRqZ22JqUQVDRrhgSLr4euF68tBHy2Bh9AN6JAFRQIJqRdcbRYKgQ0VTAcMDGI1BbKQC%20SSlLlLKrDAjQWSPCqCBQBydKCUTQAdyAA)

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript spec for the `rest parameter` is aligned with ES6's: it is the *last* arg in the param list. You should change your argument order.

from TypeScript Language Spec (#Parameter List):

> A signature’s parameter list consists of zero or more required parameters, followed by zero or more 
>   optional parameters, **finally followed by an optional rest parameter**.

from [ES6: rest parameters - Semantics](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:rest_parameters):

> The **last parameter in the [[FormalParameters]] List** is used for the rest parameter. Of the standard built-in ECMAScript objects, only Function objects implement [[HasRestParameters]].

Comment: "You should change your argument order." -- Good luck with that. Writing declarations for Node libraries, where the callback is always last? That's probably thousands of libraries that need to be rewritten...